# How to get the first letter from a string in a linked list?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, character

I tried to get the first letter from a name (type string) by `substr(0,1)`. However, I want a pointer to point at it, in a single linked list.

So I wrote it like this: `h->name.substr(0,1)` where (h) is a pointer, and (name) is a string type in a struct.

```
struct empType{
    string name;
    empType *next;
};
```

But when I printed `h->name.substr(0,1)`, it appears (NULL).

Suppose the linked list exists, and (h) is a pointer which points to the first node.

Comment: Why not `h->name[0]`?

Comment: @CoryKramer it worked thanks. I didn't know this method before.

Comment: `h->name.data()` will provide you with a pointer to the first letter.

Comment: @Ctx it gives me a syntax error saying that the expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a (reference to a) first character use the [std::basic_string::front](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) member function:

```
h->name.front();
```

or [std::basic_string::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) with a value of `0`:

```
h->name.at(0);
```

or the [std::basic_string::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) operator with the index of `0`:

```
h->name[0];
```

or dereference a [std::basic_string::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) pointer:

```
*h->name.data();
```

or dereference a [std::basic_string::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) iterator:

```
*h->name.begin();
```

Simple example that includes your struct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct empType{
    std::string name;
    empType *next;
};

int main() {
    empType* h = new empType;
    h->name = "Hello World";
    h->next = nullptr;
    std::cout << h->name.front();
    std::cout << h->name.at(0);
    std::cout << h->name[0];
    std::cout << *h->name.data();
    std::cout << *h->name.begin();
    delete h;
}
```